# Vector perpendicular to $\mathbf m$ is linear combination of $n-1$ linearly independent vectors (that are also perpendicular to $m$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $n\in\mathbb Z^+$.

(Dot product defined as usual: If $\mathbf x =(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ and $\mathbf y =(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, then $\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y = x_1y_1+x_2y_2+\dots+x_ny_n$.)

Let $\mathbf m =(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n)$ be a non-zero vector.

Let $\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\dots,\mathbf v_{n-1}$ be linearly independent vectors such that $\mathbf v_i \cdot \mathbf m = \mathbf 0$ for all $i$.

Is it then true that

> If $\mathbf x\cdot \mathbf m = 0$, then $\mathbf x$ can be written as a linear combination of $\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\dots,\mathbf v_{n-1}$?

Comment: It is true. One way to prove this starts by proving that $m$ is linearly independent from $\{v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}\}$, which implies together they make a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.